# Backward iteration using for enumerate and zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to loop the list from the last one to the first and compare adjacent elements.
To compare each two, and also get the index, I have a forward loop:

```
for index, (num1, num2) in enumerate(zip(x,x[1:]))
    do something
```

But how to start the loop from the last one?

Comment: `for ... in reversed(enumerate(...))`?

Comment: @Samwise you can't reverse a enumerate object.

Comment: @Miraboreasu Are you wanting the index to match the index of where the object is in the zipped list?

Comment: So use `…  in reversed(list(enumerate(zip(x, x[1:])))):`

Answer (score 0):

The enumeration index can't count down (but you can apply simple arithmetic).

You can reverse both lists,

```
for idx, (num1, num2) in enumerate(zip(x[::-1], x[::-1][1:])):
    ...  # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

As gruntfutuk pointed out that enumerate cannot count down. Instead you can use the range built-in function and work backwards. Here is another way of solving the problem:

```
arr = [1,3,4]
for i in range(-1, -len(arr) - 1, -1): # i will go from -1 to -3
    if i > -len(arr): # i will stop at -2
        if arr[i] == arr[i-1]:# compares arr[-1] to arr[-2] and arr[-2] to arr[-3]
            doSomething
```